# Fire Protection vs Protection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does anyone know how much the difference is between a full set of armor with at least level 4 "Fire Protection" on all items and a set of level 4 "Protection" if you swim in lava?
I'm thinking about getting a full set of protection, because it blocks most damage-types and if it would keep you alive for a good amount of time in lava, this would be my decision.

I searched Google and the MC-Wiki about this and didn't find an answer.

Comment: Please keep just one question per post. Feel free to ask your side question as it's own question, tho! (Provided it's not already answered on the site.)

Comment: In any case your answer is basically here.  http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Armor#Enchantments

Comment: @Zoredache: I didn't find this one on the wiki. Great thx. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a full set of Fire Protect IV Armor what will give you an Enchantment Protection Factor factor of 25 (9 EPF per-piece * 4, capped at 25).  This should block 100% of the fire damage you may receive.  Since the EPF is capped at 25, having 4 pieces is essentially a waste.  It only takes three pieces of armor with Fire Protect IV to cap your EPF against fire.  So you should put something else on that fourth piece of armor.

If you have a full set of Protect IV, that means your EPF will be 20 (5 EPF per piece).  This will cut the damage you take by 80%.

See: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor#Enchantments

Comment: No amount of protection will ever block 100% of damage, according to the wiki.

Comment: Right, but a capped EPF gets you about as close as you can possibly get to 100%.

Comment: But never more than 80%.

Comment: Curious side question, can you stack protection and fire protection onto one item through use of the anvil?

Comment: @Robotnik No, only one of these four can be on a piece of armor, they are not compatible with each other: _Protection_, _Blast Protection_, _Fire Protection_, _Projectile Protection_.

Comment: It's possible to enchant armors like that in 1.14.1 and 1.14.2, and armors created in these versions retain their insane protective properties through upgrade of the world.